# How to create recursive hash of hash ? (With unlimited deep)

Tags: perl, data-structures

Please, I try to create a complexe datastructure. I know how to do

```
$branch{'level1'}{'level2'}{'level3'}='leaf';
```

But I don't know how to create

```
$branch{'level1'}....{'levelN'}='leaf';
```

I try something like that :

```
$branch{'leaf'} = "1";
$branchREF = \%branch;
$branchtmp{'level3'} = $branchREF;
```

So I succefully get :

```
$VAR1 = 'level3';
$VAR2 = {
          'leaf' => '1'
        };
```

But for the next step, to do a recrusive N hash of hash, I try :

```
%branch = %branchtmp;
```

But the result is completly wrong... `%branch` is not what I'm expecting. To do my recursivity, I need to reuse my first `%branch` and not create a new one. How can I do please ?

A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to remember how perl handles multi-dimensional data structures. It does so by references. So you may find it simpler to start at the top level, as a hash ref instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @levels = qw ( level1 level2 level3 );

my $branch = {};

my $tail = pop(@levels);
my $cursor = $branch;
#iterate our levels
foreach my $level (@levels) { 
   #make a new anon-hash if there isn't one. 
   $cursor -> {$level} ||= {};
   #traverse down
   $cursor = $cursor->{$level};
}
#set a value
$cursor -> {$tail} = 'leaf';

print Dumper $branch;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'level1' => {
                        'level2' => {
                                      'level3' => 'leaf'
                                    }
                      }
        };
```

Note - you would have to reset the cursor and 're-traverse' in order to do this again, but could 'walk' the structure in a similar fashion.

Comment: This can be simplified a lot if you replace both `$cursor = ...;` with `$cursor = \( ... );` and adjust all other instances of `$cursor`. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37417801/589924).

Answer (score 5):

I strongly recommend using an existing solution such as [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Diver).

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

my @keys = map "level$_", 1 .. 3;

my $branch = {};
DiveVal($branch, map \$_, @keys) = 'leaf';
  -or-
my %branch;
DiveVal(\%branch, map \$_, @keys) = 'leaf';
```

---

Obviously, it can be done without module too.

```
sub DiveVal :lvalue {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_;
   $$p
}

my @keys = map "level$_", 1 .. 3;

my $branch;
DiveVal($branch, @keys) = 'leaf';
  -or-
my %branch;
DiveVal(\%branch, @keys) = 'leaf';
```

---

How my `DiveVal` works:

```
Pre-loop:          $p references $branch
After loop pass 0: $p references $branch->{level1}
After loop pass 1: $p references $branch->{level1}{level2}
After loop pass 2: $p references $branch->{level1}{level2}{level3}
Returned:          $branch->{level1}{level2}{level3}
```

The extra level of indirection has many benefits.

- It removes the need to treat the last key specially.
- It removes the need to create the hash before it's dereferenced.
- It removes the need for the root to be a reference to a hash. Instead, any scalar can be the root, even an undefined one.
- It makes it easy to extend `DiveVal` to support mixed array/hash structures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I've learnt a lot from it. I just want also to link to the [documentation of `:lvalue`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Lvalue-subroutines). I needed it :)

Comment: @ikegami, if you are the author of Data::Diver I've sent you an email via CPAN, i.e. to your cpan.org email address. I'm not sure if the email will be forwarded to your real email address.

Comment: @Bulrush, I do not maintain that module. My CPAN name the same as my SO name. And yeah, CPAN addresses are mail forwarders.

Answer (score 4):

[Data::Diver](http://p3rl.org/Data::Diver) can help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Diver qw{ DiveVal };
use Data::Dumper;

my %branch;
DiveVal(\%branch, map "level$_", 1 .. 3) = 'leave';
print Dumper \%branch;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'level1' => {
                        'level2' => {
                                      'level3' => 'leave'
                                    }
                      }
        };
```

Or, if you want to implement it yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

sub set_value {
    my ($struct, @list) = @_;
    if (@list > 2) {
        set_value($struct->{ $list[0] } = {}, @list[ 1 .. $#list ]);
    } else {
        $struct->{ $list[0] } = $list[1];
    }
}


my %branch;
set_value(\%branch, map("level$_", 1 .. 3), 'leave');
print Dumper \%branch;
```

Comment: Thank you Choroba. I have a preference for your second way to do it without extra module, but I find the eballes way a little bit more simple. Thank you for your answer ! :)

Comment: @choroba, You might be interested in seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37417801/589924).

Answer (score 2):

A simple recursive solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl   
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub recursiveHash {
    my ($result, @rest) = @_;
    return $result unless @rest;

    my $nextTag = pop @rest;
    return recursiveHash( {$nextTag => $result}, @rest);
}

print Dumper(recursiveHash('leaf', 'level1', 'level2', 'level3'));
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'level1' => {
                        'level2' => {
                                      'level3' => 'leaf'
                                    }
                      }
        };
```

That said, subroutine calls are rather slow in Perl. Fortunately, the recursion is completely unnecessary here.

```
sub iterativeHash {
    my ($result, @rest) = @_;
    while (@rest) {
       my $nextTag = pop @rest;
       $result = { $nextTag => $result };
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I'm impress how fast everyone answerd ! I really like the way you answer it : I don't need extra module and I find the recursive way quite elegent. So I get your answer, but the one from Sobrique and Choroba are really nice too. Thank you ! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach can't be used to add to an existing structure like `DiveVal($root, @keys) = $leaf;` can.

Answer (score 1):

I use DBM::Deep, which you will probably have to install yourself. I needed something that could handle long key values and about 100,000 keys. Normal Perl hashes (the ones installed by default) only handle a combined key and data length of 1008 bytes.

- [See Perlmonks discussion of persistent hashes](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1096995).
- [And about persistent multi-level hashes](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=512676).

---

```
# LIMITS:
# - Key size limit: none
# - Data size limit: limited by OS
# - Number of keys per hash: millions
# - Number of nested levels: millions. "Can handle millions of keys and unlimited levels without significant slow-down. "

# Basic
use Fcntl; # Required for hashes.
use DBM::Deep;
my($db);
my $fn='file.dbm';
$db=DBM::Deep->new($fn) or die "Could not make DBM::Deep in file $fn";
$db->{'key1'}="stuff";
delete $db->{'key1'};
if ($db->exists("key"))
    {
    print "Yay\n";
    }
$db->clear(); # Delete all keys.
@k=keys(%$db); # Get all first level keys.

# Alternate
my $fn='file.dbm';
tie my %db, 'DBM::Deep', $fn or die "Could not tie hash to $fn";
$db{key} = 'value';
print $db{key};

tied(%db)->put('key' => 'value');
print tied(%db)->get('key');

# Multi-level hash
$db->{'key1'}->{'subkey1'}="more stuff";
$db->{'wine'}->{'red'}->{'taste'}="good";
$db->{'invoice'}->{'16738'}->{'customernum'}=455;

# get keys or values
@k=keys(%$db);
@k=values(%$db);
@k=keys( %{$dbm->{'A'}} );  # Gets subkeys for 'A'
```