# Perl: using array to create hash of hash structure

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

within a loop I retreive

- An array (its length and data might change at each iteration)
- 1 Data name
- 1 Data value

And I would like to create a hash of hash having as structure the array and set at the end the data retreived.

exemple if I have:

```
@array = ('a','b','c');
$dataname = 'my data';
$datavalue = '123';
```

I would like to have a hash as below:

```
%hash = (
     a => {
           b => {
                 c => {
                       'my data' => '123'
                      }
                }
          }
          );
```

But i didn't find anywhere how to do it.

Comment: Take a look at [`Data::Diver`](http://search.cpan.org/~tyemq/Data-Diver-1.0101/Diver.pm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it this way, its not the most efficient but it works

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = ('a','b','c');
my $dataname = 'my data';
my $datavalue = '123';

my $hash = {$dataname => $datavalue};

foreach my $item (reverse @array){
    $hash = {$item =>$hash};
}
my %hash =%$hash;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

you will get the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => {
                   'b' => {
                            'c' => {
                                     'my data' => '123'
                                   }
                          }
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

DiveVal(\%hash, map \$_, @array, $dataname) = $datavalue;
```

Alternatively,

```
sub DiveVal :lvalue {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_;
   $$p
}

DiveVal(\%hash, @array, $dataname) = $datavalue;
```

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, [Explanation of the above code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37417801/589924). In particular, read "The extra level of indirection has many benefits" section.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, `sub {
   my $r = shift;
   $r &&= $r->{$_} for @_;
   $r
}` would be fine if you wanted to fetch from the structure, but since we're adding to the structure, we need to end up with a reference to the last value. You can do that by handling the last key specially, but the extra level of indirection makes things so much easier.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42078643/589924) does something similar, but uses aliases instead of references. Aliases using Data::Alias: `sub DiveVal :lvalue { alias my $s = shift;  alias $s = $s->{$_} for @_; $s }`. Aliases using the `refaliasing` feature: `sub DiveVal :lvalue { \my $s = \shift;  \$s = \( $s->{$_} ) for @_; $s }`.

Comment: @ikegami, Your soltion looks good but unfortunatly, that script must but run on a system on which I cannot install any additional modules and that module is not available on the target machine. I will try to find an other solution without creating the hash in that way